# SQL Server performance using ROWCOUNT

Tags: performance, sql-server-2005

I use `SET ROWCOUNT 27900` And then select two columns:

```
Select
   emp.employeeid,
   empd.employeedetailid
From
   employee emp (NOLOCK)
join 
   employeedetail empd (NOLOCK) on emp.employeeid = empd.employeeid
```

This query executes in 3 sec

If I use `SET ROWCOUNT 27950` then the same query takes 20 sec to execute.

I am not a sql DBA, why there is a difference of 17 sec for just 50 rows. Is this anything related to page size or index?

Can anyone help me to fine tune the query?

Comment: You need to get an execution plan.

Comment: There is not enough information in this question to answer it because there is no universal rule that the 27900 rows query would run at that speed and the 27950 one would not. This is something directly related to your server, and as such there could be a ton of things that impact this. In other words, there is no general solution, so we need much more specifics. Do what @Kragen said, show an execution plan for both and compare, use SQL Server Profile and check that, check disk and memory usage, etc.

Comment: See how to retrieve an execution plan: http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/explain-plan/sql-server/getting-an-execution-plan

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried doing this using `TOP` instead of `SET ROWCOUNT`, and adding an `ORDER BY`?

```
SELECT TOP 27900 emp.employeeid, ...
ORDER BY ...;
```

This will give the optimizer a much better chance at optimizing. In simplest terms, `SET ROWCOUNT` is applied *after* the entire query has been processed, and only affects the rows that are sent back to the caller...

Comment: Due to security reasons, I will not be able post the execution plan. Thank you Kragen, Markus and Aaron. Your post did help me in other ways. The server has heavily loaded and it executed normally after a while